# three.js getWorldPosition not returning expected results

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, typescript

Please refer to the gist I created at

https://gist.github.com/sparkbuzz/f1f8d0d8bbc7757b679f

It contains a TypeScript class called OrbitControls. As an attempt to learn about 3D and [three.js](http://threejs.org), I've been successful so far in creating orbit style controls, with guidance and insparation taken from [MrDoob's JS OrbitControls.](http://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_orbit.html)

My implementation is slightly different, but in a nutshell, I'm using *mousedown*, *mousemove* and *mouseup* events to navigate a camera around the world origin. When *mousedown* is fired, I grab the camera's initial position using the following code:

```
this.subjectPositionStart = this.subject.getWorldPosition();
```

which is used during *mousemove* to calculate angle's that need to be added to the camera's initial position, as it was when *mousedown* was fired.

During *mousemove*, *theta* and *phi* angles are calculated based on the distance the mouse has moved across the HTML canvas and used to reposition the camera with:

```
this.subject.position.x = rho * Math.cos(theta) * Math.sin(phi);
this.subject.position.y = rho * Math.sin(theta) * Math.sin(phi);
this.subject.position.z = rho * Math.cos(phi);
```

Everything works fine, however, on the next *mousedown*, sometimes, when the rotation angle of the camera's position around the z-axis goes either above 90° , or below -90°, the camera position snaps to a position that looks inverse of what it's supposed to be.

So what I'm seeing is that the camera flips, to mirror its position, the degrees are correct, but just mirrored.

When I don't exceed the 90° the next *mousedown* works fine and navigation behaves as expected, and the camera position is correctly retrieved from *getWorldPosition()*, but I suspect that I'm using this function incorrectly, or perhaps entirely using the wrong technique to determine the angles for the camera's position in relation to the origin.

The problem is definitely to do with the *mousedown* handler, as while only *mousemove* fires, there's no problem in exceeding the 90° angles, and navigation works fine.

Any ideas on what could be wrong?

EDIT:

I think the way I'm [calculating baseTheta](https://gist.github.com/sparkbuzz/f1f8d0d8bbc7757b679f#file-orbitcontrols-ts-L108) is incorrect:

```
var baseTheta:number = Math.asin(this.subjectPositionStart.y / rho / Math.sin(basePhi));
```

If I use:

```
var baseTheta:number = Math.acos(this.subjectPositionStart.x / rho / Math.sin(basePhi));
```

I get the same problem, but it flips on between 180° and 360°, and I'm thinking that's a clue...

Comment: I looked at the possibility of lookAt() messing around, but it doesn't seem so, what I can see however, after adding some debug overlay data, is that whenever X becomes negative, on the next mousedown, the calculation causes the - to become + somehow, for example if X was -0.5 it will jump to 0.5. Y and Z values remain correct however...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem might have something to do with the way Three.js tries to keep the camera facing up

Check this out: [rotating-camera-around-the-x-axis-three-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11648869/rotating-camera-around-the-x-axis-three-js)

In the [Orbit controls source](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js) there are some limits to how for one can rotate. Adding these to your code might fix your problem.

```
        // restrict theta to be between desired limits
        theta = Math.max( this.minAzimuthAngle, Math.min( this.maxAzimuthAngle, theta ) );

        // restrict phi to be between desired limits
        phi = Math.max( this.minPolarAngle, Math.min( this.maxPolarAngle, phi ) );

        // restrict phi to be betwee EPS and PI-EPS
        phi = Math.max( EPS, Math.min( Math.PI - EPS, phi ) );
```

Comment: I'll definitely try this, but as long as I'm not calling getWorldPosition, for example while continuously dragging the mouse with the mouse button down, this is never a problem. the camera orbits as expected. Only when calling getWorldPosition to reset the initial position for mousemove, in the mousedown event, and when the camera angle around the z-axis is > 90° or < -90° this problem occurs.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out *baseTheta* and *basePhi* weren't being calculated correctly, and it the question actually turned up in a different question I asked.

[Calculate θ and ø angles between origin and x,y,z coordinate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31193614/calculate-%CE%B8-and-%C3%B8-angles-between-origin-and-x-y-z-coordinate)

I changed the following code, with the help of Paul.S's answer in the link above from:

```
var basePhi:number = Math.acos(this.subjectPositionStart.z / rho);
var baseTheta:number = Math.asin(this.subjectPositionStart.y / rho / Math.sin(basePhi));
```

to

```
var basePhi:number = Math.acos(this.subjectPositionStart.z / rho);
var baseTheta:number = Math.atan2(this.subjectPositionStart.y, this.subjectPositionStart.x);
```

and the problem was solved. No more flippin flipping about.

Comment: Glad you were able to solve your problem and thx for positing your solution.